# Can I recover remotely deleted files?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-server-2003, file-recovery

I accessed a certain computers files, which is running an XP OS, via the Run.exe. (ex. \100.000.111.104\c$)
Then I accidentally deleted some files in it.
I was accessing the other computer using a Windows server 2003 OS computer.

Is there some ways for me to recover the deleted files?

Comment: Not unless the remote computer has a backup of the now deleted files...

Comment: Thanks for commenting. Unfortunately I don't have a backup of those files on the remote computer.

Comment: Unfortunately, if you don't have a backup then you're going to need to use some recovery software to see if you can get the files back (run this on the remote computer, not the server) or take it as a massive learning curve not to delete stuff without being absolutely certain it is safe to do so...

Comment: Well, there's Shadow Copy aka File History, but since the server is running Windows 2003, it's too old for that...

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible, read on.

Unfortunately, files deleted over a Windows network cannot be undeleted through Windows, as they do not go into the Recycle Bin.

Typically (there are always exceptions, but no need to get into that for this discussion), when you delete a file locally on a Windows OS, the files get moved to the Recycle Bin.  The Recycle Bin keeps the files until they are permanently deleted, or the system needs space.

However, this does not mean they are gone forever.  When Windows' Recycle Bin deletes a file, it just marks that space as free.  The same goes for files that were deleted and did not go into the Recycle Bin.  As long as the clusters on the disk havent been overwritten, you might be in luck.  You can try using a file recovery tool like [Recuva](https://www.piriform.com/recuva/download) on the XP machine's hard drive.

To be safe, you should shutdown the XP machine ASAP.  Remove the hard drive and attach it to another computer.  A USB adapter like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000YJBL78) is an excellent and cheap tool to have.  Install the file recovery software on the *other* computer!  Why?  The installation of the recovery software could overwrite the files you want to recover.

If you are lucky, you might be able to restore some, or even all of the deleted files.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting files from remote directories deletes the files permanently so you would require a backup of the deleted files and restore them from the backup.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the XP machine, AND you haven't created any new files or made any really big changes to the files, then it's possible.  First, STOP WHAT YOU ARE DOING on that machine.  Then you'll need to download an undelete program on a DIFFERENT machine and save it to a USB drive or burn it to a disk.  I used to use [this](http://www3.telus.net/mikebike/RESTORATION.html) program when trying to recover things I accidentally deleted a long time ago.  There's a lot of them lately, [this](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/filerecovery/tp/free-file-recovery-programs.htm) link has a list of them.  I've had luck with the EaseUS one too.

If you're not using an SSD, then the OS isn't going to actually delete the contents of deleted files after it's been deleted.  It just marks the space on the hard drive as free, and when another file needs space, then it will overwrite it.  If you don't create or update the files on the system after you've deleted something, then you can still recover things you've deleted.  Even after a quick format, it's possible to recover files.  If you do a slow format, then the data is gone.